# A property of Levy collapse forcing

Tags: reference-request, set-theory, forcing

Consider the following nice property for a forcing notion $\mathbb{P}$ (in a transitive model $M$ of $\mathtt{ZFC}$):

> Let $G_1,G_2$ $\mathbb{P}$-generic over $M$ and $M[G_1]$ respectively. Then, if $G_1' \in M[G_1]$ is $\mathbb{P}$-generic over $M$, there exists $G'_2$ $\mathbb{P}$-generic over $M[G_1']$ such that $M[G_1'][G_2'] = M[G_1][G_2]$

Solovay, in his paper on Solovay model, proved that Levy collapse satisfies this property (hence in particular also the Cohen forcing $Fn(\omega,2)$).
My questions are:

1. Has this property been studied in his own regard?
2. Does Silver forcing (whose conditions are partial maps from $\omega$ onto $2$ with co-infinite domains) have this property?

Thanks!

Comment: I mean, it's just a consequence of the conjunction of the facts that $M[G_1]$ is a generic extension of $M[G_1']$ and that any nontrivial quotient of $\Bbb P$ is isomorphic to $\Bbb P$. This holds for $\operatorname{Col}(\omega,\alpha)$ for any infinite $\alpha$, and in case for $\alpha=\omega$, it is just the Cohen forcing again.

Comment: It's been awhile, but if I recall correctly, the factoring property of the collapse is not held by Silver's forcing. Silver's forcing should be equivalent to a countably-closed * ccc iteration.